# Passing Recordset Data as Argument

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

In this particular code I'm trying to test if a double meets a certain condition. This double is generated by converting an input from a recordset (which should be a string) to a double.

Below is the code in question:

```
Do Until SampleTable.EOF
If (isCancer(convertValuetoNumeric(SampleTable![Value]))) Then
    'Some stuff done here
    '...
End If
```

I get an "Compile Error: Type Mismatch" error with my convertValuetoNumeric method highlighted. Now the input is highly normalized so I know that any string passed to the convert method will return as a double. I believe the error is from either the fact that the argument passed to convertValuetoNumeric is already a double or because that calling data from the table is return a RecordSet object and not a String as I am expecting.

Below is the conversion code:

```
Function convertValuetoNumeric(ICD As String) As Double
 If IsNumeric(ICD) Then
     convertValuetoNumeric = CDbl(ICD)
 Else
     convertValuetoNumeric = CDbl(Replace(ICD, "V", "99")) 'Replace V with 99 and convert
 End If
 End Function
```

The input would either be a double (e.g. 1000.5) or a double with a V preceding it (e.g. V100000.5). The program would either return the variable as a double unchanged or with as a double with a 99 at the front of it. No input would ever break those two scenarios.

EDIT: Even changing the method signature of convertValuetoNumeric() to accept a variable of type `Variant` instead of `String` does nothing to fix the error.

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing `convertValuetoNumeric` and examples of the input values.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added in the convert code for you

Comment: if the input to convertValuetoNumeric is a string then it will fail since it's expecting a double...  You could change the inpur parameter type to Variant if it could be a number or a string.  What does `Msgbox TypeName(SampleTable![Value])` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Variant ICD that will be valid in both VBA and VBScript:

```
Function convertValuetoNumeric(ByVal ICD) As Double
  If IsNumeric(ICD) Then
     convertValuetoNumeric = CDbl(ICD)
  Else
    convertValuetoNumeric = CDbl(Replace(ICD, "V", "99")) 'Replace V with 99 and convert
  End If
End Function
```

And in the call:

```
Do Until SampleTable.EOF
  If (isCancer(convertValuetoNumeric(SampleTable![Value].Value))) Then
      'Some stuff done here
      '...
  End If
....
```

I suppose that [Value] is the column name.

Comment: Happy that this is useful for you.